# Colors/Lights drastically different in render (2.8 Eevee)

Tags: rendering, color-management

Trying to get back into Blender after a bit of a hiatus. [I am not sure what is going wrong. When I am in my rendered viewport the colors look perfect and then as soon as I go to render the animation/image the colors get blown out like crazy.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YgZsT7Kiks4&feature=youtu.be)

I have messed with color management settings (filmic, standard, none, etc) and they all look like garbage. If anyone has a suggestion that would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked if any objects are hidden in the render? It would also help if you uploaded your blend to https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ Just edit the given code into your question.

Answer (score 1):

Try disabling "Bloom" or adjust it's settings and see if you have the same issue.

[image]